# Change Orientation within the same controller scope

Tags: ios

I have three uiwebviews in a single view controller. Initially the app is set for landscape mode only in General settings. Initially I load the first webview having the other two webviews hidden. Now when i load the second webview, I need to allow for all orientations for this particular webview. Is it possible to change orientation for a webview within the same controller scope? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <objc/message.h>

 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)]) {
     objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:),    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );
}
```